# ScalaJs 0.9: getting HTML input value without jQuery

Tags: html, scala, scala.js

I'm using ScalaJS and I want to read the value of an HTML `input` element.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<input id="nodeValue" type="number" step="1" />
```

And this is the Scala code:

```
object TutorialApp extends JSApp {
    // ...
    def addNode() = {
        val nodeValue = document.getElementById("nodeValue").value.toInt
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile, as

```
[error] TutorialApp.scala:42: value value is not a member of org.scalajs.dom.raw.Element
[error]     val nodeValue = document.getElementById("nodeValue").value.toInt
```

In the documentation, I can't find the `value` attribute of `org.scalajs.dom.raw.Element`.

In the official [basic tutorial](https://www.scala-js.org/tutorial/basic/) it uses immediately to jQuery, but I'd avoid it since I'm working on a small proof of concept. I'm sure there's a way to use just the DOM API.

EDIT:

Going through the documentation I found the `nodeValue` method which returns a string. It says though that is `null` for "most node types".
Mine is `number` and indeed fails at runtime, returning null.
Another edit: it returns `null` also for a text input.

I feel a bit bewildered at this point.

thanks,
Pietro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume the element you're fetching (`nodeValue`) is an `<input>` element.

`getElementById` does not know what kind of element `nodeValue` is. It does not have access to the .html to figure that out, and hence it returns a very generic `Element`. But in fact, *you* know that it is an *input* element, i.e., an `org.scalajs.dom.html.Input`. You can tell that to the compiler with `.asInstanceOf[html.Input]`. A generic `Element` does not have a `value` property, only `Input`s have.

```
import org.scalajs.dom.html

val nodeValue = document.getElementById("nodeValue").asInstanceOf[html.Input].value.toInt
```

Comment: Would it be better to generate the html directly in scalajs? Like with scalatags?